# Initialize a private aggregate from a braced-init-list

Tags: c++, aggregate, c++14, list-initialization

If I try to compile

```
class triangle
{
private:
    std::array<std::array<double, 2>, 3> m_vertices;
};

triangle const unit_triangle{ { { { 0, 0 }, { 1, 0 }, { 0, 1 } } } };
```

I get the error message

> cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'triangle'.

If I replace `private` by `public`, the code compiles successfully. Since I don't want to do that: What do I need to do, if I want to initialize `unit_triangle` from a braced-init-list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having a `private` member prevents `triangle` from being an [aggregate](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization). It's being an aggregate that allows you to list-initialize a `triangle` without `triangle` having a constructor. That's why it works when you replace `private` with `public`.

To support the syntax you want, you simply need to add the appropriate constructor. In this case:

```
class triangle
{
public:
    triangle(std::array<std::array<double, 2>, 3> const& v)
        : m_vertices(v)
    { }

private:
    std::array<std::array<double, 2>, 3> m_vertices;
};
```